# Assets are redirecting to https instead of http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, puma

Client gave me a ruby application to deploy on AWS EC2. I have configured it but after login page all assets are redirecting to https.
In html the src='http://{url}' but in Network tab all request are checking https and so failing to load.

I have set force_ssl = false in configuration files as well.

The error comes as ' HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP                               format, parsing fails.>
'

Is there any other place where I need to update settings? Previously the site is configured with SSL and now I am trying without SSL

The login page is working fine by the way. but after that it makes every call to https

Comment: were you able to fix the issue? I'm seeing it on AWS Fargate

Comment: I went to a trouble of buying a domain and deploying application on domain worked for me. Not sure whats really written in the code but somehow it is tightly coupled with a domain and always look for one with http